# Share an instance of a class across a JAX-WS or JAX-RS Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jax-rs

I have built a class (call it `RecordManager`) which manages data on a file system. I would like to make SOAP or REST calls that change the state of this class. However I only want to have one instance of this class running for every call to the server.

How do I create one instance of this class and be able to use it given all JAX-WS or JAX-RS calls? Ideally I would like to just call:

```
 @GET 
 public ... (...){
      rec_man.update( <parameters passed by call> )
 }
```

where `rec_man` is the instance of `RecordManager`

I'm fairly certain that I have ensured thread safety with this class.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand correctly, but it sounds like you want RecordManager to be static. Here's a possible duplicate question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311331/how-to-initialize-static-variables-in-web-services

Comment: Yeah thats the question! I was wondering how to word it. However I need to be able to do this in java. Could you point me to a resource and the wording/questions I need to ask in order to figure this out?

Comment: Aren't they asking about using a Singleton?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RecordManager {
   public static final RecordManager INSTANCE = new RecordManager();
   private RecordManager() {
         // private constructor prevents instantiation
   }
}
```

Your JAX-WS service or JAX-RS resource would reference RecordManager like this:

```
 @GET 
 public ... (...){
      ...
      rec_man = RecordManager.INSTANCE;
      rec_man.update( <parameters passed by call> )
 }
```

Or, if you don't like that style (singleton as a public static instance) you could hide the static instance and expose a static method to obtain it.

```
public class RecordManager {
   private static RecordManager instance;
   private RecordManager() {
         // private constructor prevents instantiation
   }

   public static RecordManager getInstance() {
       if (instance == null) {
           instance = new RecordManager();
           ... init
       }
       return instance;
   }
}
```

Your usage becomes:

```
 @GET 
 public ... (...){
      ...
      rec_man = RecordManager.getInstance();
      rec_man.update( <parameters passed by call> )
 }
```

Note that if your instantiation logic needs to be threadsafe (e.g. only *ever* initialize once) then you could make the `getInstance` method `synchronized` or one of the techniques described in [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html).